# how to fine-tune/modify XFCE4 Theme? (Blackbird theme issue fix to ALT+TAB nicely)

Tags: xubuntu, themes, xfce, colors

There is an inconvenient bug in Xubuntu 19.10 making ALT+TABbing very unclear since there is no highlighting any more - I need to know **where exactly may I modify how highlighting looks like** in the theme while tabbing windows?

I've gone to `/usr/share/themes/Blackbird/` but there are too many lines to walk through :(

I am able to direct-edit files, no need to any GUI. Thanks!

Here is what it looks like:
[image: error in Blackbird]

other theme works fine:
[image: Greybirds works]

PS: I've posted an official bugreport here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-settings/+bug/1854035

Comment: nobody has a hint? it really annoys me :/